# Как можно менять в рантайме строку подключения к БД?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, winforms, wcf

Wcf + консольное приложение(хост) + entity framework

Есть консольное приложение в качестве хоста wcf-службы. Как можно менять в рантайме строку подключения к БД? Как я понял оба (сервис и хост) должны знать эту строку.

Answer (score 1):

По хорошему, хосту не должно быть ничего известно о внутреннем устройстве сервисов (строки подключения к БД и тп).
Если в вашем приложении хосту требуется строка подключения, значит что то вы плохо спроектировали.

Comment: Поменял строку подключения в сервисе. Вроде работает как надо. Не помню уже, но при тестировании сервиса через хостинг в консольном приложении, он возвращал ошибку при попытке выборки данных. Нашел решение - добавить строку подключения EntityFramework в app.config хоста.